# How to add different Custom Cells in one TableView with Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard, custom-cell

i want to add 2 or more diffrent Custom cells in one Tableview, by using storyboard.
i know how to add diffrent cells without storyboard. I always do this by this way:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//pictureCell = [[DetailPictureCell alloc]init];//(DetailPictureCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
pictureCell.header = true;
[pictureCell setHeader];
if (cell == nil) {
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderAngebotViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        NSLog(@"New Header Cell");
}
    if([indexPath row] ==1){
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"productCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And now my question: How i can do this with storyboard?
To add one custom cell is possible. But i can not add two diffrent cell. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the attributes inspector for the table view, select "Dynamic Prototypes" and below that select the number of prototype cells. Give each cell a different identifier and when dequeuing cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use the appropriate identifier based on indexPath.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        identifier = @"OneCellId";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        identifier = @"OtherCellId";
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    //configure cell...
}
```

Comment: thanks!can you post an example how it works with the appropriate identifier based in index path?

Comment: i've done it like you said. And i get an error. "Tableview datasource must return a cell from tableview:cellforrowatindexpath" Maybe i forgot something? I have linked the cell in the storyboard to custom cell, and the labels also.                                     ...NSInteger row = [indexPath row]; NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *identifier;    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (row == 0) {identifier =@"ThirdCell";
    cell.clubNameLabel.text =@"%@",[clubname objectAtIndex:row];
            }return cell;....

Comment: You're either not getting a cell back from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` or you're not returning it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. From your comment, I would guess it is the former because you're calling dequeue before setting a value for `identifier`. In any case, you should put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and step through to see where things go wrong.